# Recovering the string split by string.split() in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string "**I love A. I hate B**". If I split it by using

```
 string.split("\\p{Punct}")
```

I will get two strings where `string1` will be "**I love A**" and `string2` will be "**I hate B**". Please note that in place of "**.**" I may also have any of the other punctuation characters. How can I recover the exact string as it was before the splitting operation with the correct punctuation character.

Comment: u mean i can't keep a record of what matched the regex?

Comment: In Perl it would be as simple as `split( /(\p{Punct})/, $string )`. This would result in a list of 3 elements `( 'I love A', '.', 'I hate B' )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split using the following regular expression (using a [zero-width look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
(?<=\p{Punct})
```

It will not actually consume the punctuation character, but just check that there is a punctuation character directly before the split point.  As a result, the punctuation characters are left in the final strings:

```
String s = "I love A. I hate B.";
String res[] = s.split("(?<=\\p{Punct})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Result:

```
[I love A.,  I hate B.]
```

Now you could concatenate the elements of the array back together to recover the original string.

Demo: http://ideone.com/0umjkZ

Answer (score 6):

Keep a reference to the string - if you can have any punct, you can't guess what you had before

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer and manage the elements with the method nextElement().

Sample.

```
String str = "I love A. I hate B";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,".");

String beforeElement;
String otherElement;

while (st.hasMoreElements()){

    beforeElement=st.nextElement();

     if(st.hasMoreElements()){

       otherElement=st.nextElement();

    }

}
```